# Can two nouns appear together in a sentence without a punctuation or a conjunction?

Tags: linguistics

I am a new NLP engineer and totally a beginner in English linguistics. I want to know if two nouns can appear together in a sentence without a punctuation or a conjunction between both of them? Also, the two nouns should reflect two different entities, not one. 
For example,

> The name of the president is Donald Trump.

Part of Speech tagger in NLP tags Donald and Trump as NNP (proper noun) respectively. But in the real world, Donald Trump is one entity.

Thank you.

Comment: It can happen with a restrictive apposition, like "my brother Bob", but maybe you'd still consider that to be one entity.

Comment: @Ami Perhaps better would be "of my three brothers, my **brothers Bob** and Doug had left home." (Or is *Bob* a "member" of the entity *brothers*?)

Comment: For my use case, brother and Bob will be two different entities. Same goes for brothers and Bob. Thanks for the examples!

Comment: Why at all do you think that should not happen? Is there such a rule in your native language? See also: my comment at the answer by ruakh below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely; consider e.g. "I fed the guests dinner". Or heck, consider just "orange juice".

This can be taken to extremes: "I fed the quantum physics professor banana chocolate chip muffins."

Comment: There are quite some ways and reasons how and why nouns can occur consecutively without intervening punctuation. In short, there's no rule at all why any number of nouns cannot run on and on.

Comment: @Kris: Agreed. The OP seemed only interested in whether this can happen *at all*, so I just selected a few common ways. Other ways include things like "the games people play", things like "Truth is beauty, beauty truth", things like "Is Donald Trump president?", and . . . well, probably lots and lots of things I'm not thinking of. It doesn't seem productive to attempt a full list.

Comment: For ironic effect: "noun phrase".